# Both importrange and script are failing to copy all records

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I have a Google sheet which uses an importrange function and has worked for several years.  for some reason, it has suddenly started to fail to copy a couple of rows in the middle of other data and is failing to copy the newest records.
I have tried deleting and restoring the importrange formula in the destination sheet with the same result.
thinking that it might be related to the amount of data to be imported, I also tried an arrayformula approach but the result is the same.
since neither of these worked, I have tried a script to getValues instead of using importrange but again the result is the same.
it's as if the originating data that is missing from the destination sheet is simply not in the originating sheet even though it's clearly visible.
to make matters even more confusing, if I try to print the data in question from a highlighted range in the originating sheet, the missing data which is interspersed with data that is successfully copied shows in the print preview but the data at the end of the sheet which does not get copied is missing from the preview.  (see attached).
[image: Print Preview]

the interspersed data that is missing from the destination file is for records 2006 and 2009.  in addition, I am missing the last 6 records (rows) in the destination file which are clearly included in the originating file.
I have included screen shots of the originating data, the destination data and the script I am using.
hoping someone can help me with this.  I've never seen anything like it.

[image: Destination Data][image: Originating Data]

[image: getValue Script]

---

```
function initializeNewClientOrder() {

//this seript replaces importrange functions in the New Client Order Log UI Control V4.8

//import the ID Clean worksheet from the Contact Update Log file https://docs.google.con/spreadsheet

// define destination file
var destkey = "1J18WSFdP1UpgNQVISCuFaKKb1x-NRgouQUehoMaX3ok"
var destsheet = "Import Contact Log New"

//open destination file
var destfile = SpreadsheetApp.openByld(destkey) .getSheetByNane (destsheet) ;

//define source file
var sourcekey = "1PGS3EQ1ntXNrHONNACDESZ6ASKVFBCUY1nDUUHVO-ek"
//var sourcesheet = “ID Clean";
var sourcesheet = "test";

//open source file
var sourcefile = SpreadsheetApp.openByld(sourcekey).getSheetByName(sourcesheet) ;
// define file array for sourcefile
var lastRow = sourcefile.getRange("O1").getValue();
//var lastRow = 1852

//startrow, firsteol, rowcount, lasteol
var startrow = 2
var firstcol = 1
var rowcount = lastRow + 1
var lastcol = 12

//get the data from the source file
var sourcedata = sourcefile.getRange(startrow, firstcol, rowcount, lastcol).getValues()

//write the data back to the destination file
destfile.getRange(startron, firstcol, rowcount, lastcol) . setValues(sourcedata) ;

}
```

---

Comment: Hi and welcome to WebApps. Interesting (and frustrating) problem! Just to clarify... By way of troubleshooting, you used a script to get the data and the script failed to select all the records. The problem that you are experiencing is either 1) records 2006 to 2009 are not being imported and/or 2) the final six records are not being imported. Is that right?

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. 1. Code should be added, properly formatted, as text, not as image. 2. Add the values that are read from the spreadsheet  i.e. the value of `O1` from the `sourcefile` 3. Add more details like the IMPORTRANGE formula that you are using and ensure that details about your spreadsheet are enough for others be able to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Without (understandably) having your spreadsheet to work with, I think our best approach is to assist with debugging. In the first instance, I think the most important issue is to confirm the actual data range in your sourcesheet.

The following script will access your source spreadsheet and identify the actual data range as well as an specific count of the data rows in Column A. Results are displayed in Logger statements.

Run this script (from a clean spreadsheet), make a note of the reported data range, and then review the source file to confirm that data range and row count.

---

```
function confirmdatarange() {

// create a blank spreadsheet. Insert and run this script in that file.
// this script opens the source spreadsheet and sheet 
// it uses several methods to determine the last row of data
// and displays the various data ranges to the user

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1")

//define source file
var sourcekey = "INSERT SOURCEKEY"
var sourcesheet = "INSERT SHEET NAME"

//open source file
var sourcefile = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sourcekey)
var sourcesheet = sourcefile.getSheetByName(sourcesheet)
Logger.log("DEBUG: Spreadsheet name:"+sourcefile.getName()+"\nsheet name:"+sourcesheet.getName())

// get the last row by looking at Column A
// this test assumes contiguous data rows
var Avals = sourcesheet.getRange("A1:A").getValues()
var Alast = Avals.filter(String).length
Logger.log("DEBUG: the last row reported for Column A = "+Alast)

// use getlastrow
var lastRow = sourcesheet.getLastRow()
Logger.log("DEBUG: According to getlastrow, the last row with content = "+lastRow)

//startrow, firsteol, rowcount, lasteol
var startrow = 2
var endrow = lastRow-1 // because the start row excludes row 1(headers?)
var firstcol = 1
var lastcol = 12

//get the data range from the sourcesheet
var sourcerange = sourcesheet.getRange(startrow, firstcol, lastRow-1, lastcol)
Logger.log("DEBUG: The data range = "+sourcerange.getA1Notation())

}
```

---

**Sample**

The Logger statements should look something like this

[image: snapshot]